# How to get current Spring profile in jsp file.

Tags: java, spring, jsp, profile

I'm developing Spring MVC application. In my application I have two profiles, test and production. Test is enable when I deploy my app to test envirionemnt, Production on production environment.

I need to get current profile in jsp file. Is it possible ? I don't want to send additional variable to get this information because file is included to lot of others files. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
ServletContext sc = request.getSession().getServletContext();
WebApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sc);
String[] profiles = applicationContext.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response but, sorry, I don't understand it.
I asked if can I get information which profile is active from JSP code. 
Whay should I store additional properties in file or database to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using MVC, a more straightforward approach is to autowire the environment in your controller and pass the profiles in the model.

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@RequestMapping("/needsProfile")
public String needsProfile(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("profiles", environment.getActiveProfiles());
    return "needsProfile";
}
```

And in your needsProfile.jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="profiles" type="java.lang.String[]" scope="request"/>

<%-- ... --%>

<div>First Profile:  ${profiles[0]}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but maybe someone is still searching for it.

There is a easy way to access environment in jsp without implement custom classes or taglibs:

```
<spring:eval expression="@environment.getActiveProfiles()"></spring:eval>
```

of course jsp must declare:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
```

I'm using spring 4.2 but it is implemented since 3.0.1

Comment: this should be the way nowadays

Answer (score 1):

For a more elegant way, you can create a custom JSP tag. Here is a tutorial you can use to achieve this: http://blog.florianlopes.io/access-spring-profiles-with-custom-jsp-tag/

With this custom tag, you will be able to restrict an area based on the active Spring profile.

This idea is to extend the Spring ***RequestContextAwareTag***. It will give your custom tag access to Spring profiles. Extending this class, the implementation is straightforward:

```
public class ProfileConditionTag extends RequestContextAwareTag {

    private String expectedProfile;

    @Override
    protected int doStartTagInternal() throws Exception {
        final Environment environment = this.getRequestContext().getWebApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
        if (environment != null) {
            final String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
            if (ArrayUtils.contains(activeProfiles, this.expectedProfile)) {
                return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
            }
        }

        return SKIP_BODY;
    }

    // Getters, setters
}
```

The **SKIP_BODY** return value tells the JSP processor to skip the tag body if the active profile is not the one expected.

1. Create the taglib description and import the tag:

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="tagprefix" uri="/WEB-INF/taglib/profile.tld" %>
   ```
2. Use it:

   `<tagprefix:profile value="dev">
       Only displayed if the active Spring profile is "dev".
   </tagprefix:profile>`